# Trace of a script module in TorchScript

Tags: pytorch, torch, pytorch-lightning, torchscript

Is there any way to convert a script module created by `torch.jit.script` to a traced script module?

After creating a model with code

```
import torch
from torch import nn
from torch import optim
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
import numpy as np

class TheModelClass(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TheModelClass, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 6, 5)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16 * 5 * 5, 120)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        x = x.view(-1, 16 * 5 * 5)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x

# Initialize model
model = TheModelClass()

# Initialize optimizer
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)
```

I am saving the scriptmodule from its script

```
m = torch.jit.script(model)    
torch.jit.save(m, "model.pt")
```

The saved model will be later used, and I am required to find its trace with example inputs. Is there any way to do so?
When I try to do this,

```
model=torch.jit.load('model.pt')
dummy=torch.rand((1,3,224,224))
model=torch.jit.trace(model.code, dummy)
```

Following is thrown,

```
UserWarning: The input to trace is already a ScriptModule, tracing it is a no-op. Returning the object as is.
```

Comment: May i ask why do you need to trace a script module when you already have converted to a libtorch object

Comment: @EdwinCheong I want to find what exact operations are present in the nodes in the model graph based on provided inputs, thus making the script module input independent, similar to what trace does.

Comment: I would also be interested in doing this, because warmup of model may take a minute if scripted while it is instantaneous with tracing in my case.